# Epub reader with annotation support

Tags: windows, gratis, epub

I know that there is a plugin for Calibre and that Edge on Windows 10 supports this but both are not what I'm searching for.

The epub reader I search for should have:

- supported on Windows, preferably Linux too
- runs with files stored in the local filesystem without need to upload them to a store or cloud based service
- store the annotation in or next to the epub file
- cheap or even better gratis
- support highlighting of text too

Reasons for this: I store all my epubs in Dropbox and read and annotate them on several computers. When I annotated a file on one of them I want to see the same on any other computer. I don't want to be locked in by using a specific epub cloud service because in the past I annotated tens of ebooks using an iPad Kindle app and lost all of them and don't want to experience the same again

Answer (score 2):

Bluefire and Adobe Digital Editions have it. Bluefire's annotation is better since you can export a neat (organized) set of notes and highlights; both of them have their issues however and Bluefire for Windows is no longer in development. I'm still looking for something which bridges the gap, so do let me know if you find it.

edit: Foliate is a great solution on Linux as of its recent updates.